# Get unix hostname from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, unix, command, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS to develop a script that will be executed on Unix server.
From PhantomJS, I want to get the name of the Unix system as returned by the `hostname` command.

I do this

```
var childProcess = require('child_process')

childProcess.execFile("hostname", [""], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout))
  console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr))
  console.log("execFileERR:", JSON.stringify(err))
})
```

But nothing is display.

Comment: Is this your full script? I suspect that you're exiting too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `execFile` is asynchronous. If you're exiting your PhantomJS script, then you need to do this in the callback. Furthermore, `""` is not a valid hostname. You can use an empty argument list:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process')

childProcess.execFile("hostname", [], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout))
  console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr))
  console.log("execFileERR:", JSON.stringify(err))
  phantom.exit();
})
```

Output:

```
execFileSTDOUT: "myhostname\n"
execFileSTDERR: ""
execFileERR: null
```

Tested with PhantomJS 1.9.7 and 2.0.1.

Comment: OK with PhantomJS 2.0.0. Do you think, is it possible to execute `execFile` synchronously ?

Answer (score 0):

Lose the 2nd and 3rd parameters (you're not sending anything so it's ok)

```
var childProcess = require('child_process')

childProcess.execFile("hostname", [], {}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout))
  console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr))
  console.log("execFileERR:", JSON.stringify(err))
})

// execFileSTDOUT: "YourPuterName\n"
```

Comment: I got this error :  Error: incompatible type of argument(s) in call to _start(); candidates were
    _start(QString,QStringList)

  :95 in _start
  :95 in execFile

Comment: Which version of Node are you running?

Comment: PhantomJS V 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 15.04 - ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)

Comment: @Wainage PhantomJS is completely independent of node. It has only two modules of the same name, but different functions and implementations.

Comment: @LeMoussel. I've updated my code and tested it on PhantomJS 2.1.1. Works great. You must pass in an empty array or else it seems the empty string gets sent to `hostname ""` which doesn't product results.